Groupby - filling missing component of group
It is hard to describe my problem so I will start with the sample data first, explain data, then point out what I am looking for
Sample data:
data = [
    # Company 1
    ['Company 1', 2000, '1234', 1],
    ['Company 1', 2000, '5678', 2],
    ['Company 1', 2000, '9101', 3],
    ['Company 1', 2000, '1121', 4],
    ['Company 1', 2001, '1234', 5],
    ['Company 1', 2001, '5678', 6],
    ['Company 1', 2001, '9101', 7],
    ['Company 1', 2001, '1121', 8],
    ['Company 1', 2002, '1234', 9],
    ['Company 1', 2002, '5678', 10],
    ['Company 1', 2002, '9101', 11],
    ['Company 1', 2002, '1121', 12],
    ['Company 1', 2003, '1234', 13],
    ['Company 1', 2003, '5678', 14],
    ['Company 1', 2003, '9101', 15],
    ['Company 1', 2003, '1121', 16],
    ['Company 1', 2004, '1234', 17],
    ['Company 1', 2004, '5678', 18],
    ['Company 1', 2004, '9101', 19],
    ['Company 1', 2004, '1121', 20],

    # Company 2
    ['Company 2', 2000, '2345', 21],
    ['Company 2', 2000, '6789', 22],
    ['Company 2', 2000, '3456', 23],
    ['Company 2', 2001, '2345', 24],
    ['Company 2', 2001, '6789', 25],
    ['Company 2', 2001, '3456', 26],
    ['Company 2', 2002, '2345', 27],
    ['Company 2', 2002, '6789', 28],
    ['Company 2', 2002, '3456', 29],
    ['Company 2', 2005, '2345', 30],
    ['Company 2', 2005, '6789', 31],
    ['Company 2', 2005, '3456', 32],
    ['Company 2', 2006, '2345', 33],
    ['Company 2', 2006, '6789', 34],
    ['Company 2', 2006, '3456', 35],
    ['Company 2', 2007, '2345', 36],
    ['Company 2', 2007, '6789', 37],
    ['Company 2', 2007, '3456', 38],

    # Company 3
    ['Company 3', 2000, '4567', 39],
    ['Company 3', 2000, '7890', 40],
    ['Company 3', 2000, '3456', 41],
    ['Company 3', 2001, '4567', 42],
    ['Company 3', 2001, '7890', 43],
    ['Company 3', 2001, '9123', 44],
    ['Company 3', 2002, '4567', 45],
    ['Company 3', 2002, '7890', 46],
    ['Company 3', 2002, '8345', 47],
    ['Company 3', 2003, '4567', 48],
    ['Company 3', 2003, '7890', 49],
    ['Company 3', 2003, '5673', 50],
    ['Company 3', 2004, '4567', 51],
    ['Company 3', 2004, '7890', 52],
    ['Company 3', 2004, '3456', 53],

    # Company 4
    ['Company 4', 2000, '4000', 54],
    ['Company 4', 2000, '7000', 55],
    ['Company 4', 2000, '1000', 56],
    ['Company 4', 2001, '4000', 57],
    ['Company 4', 2001, '7000', 58],
    ['Company 4', 2001, '6000', 59],
    ['Company 4', 2003, '4000', 60],
    ['Company 4', 2003, '7000', 61],
    ['Company 4', 2003, '3000', 62],
    ['Company 4', 2004, '4000', 63],
    ['Company 4', 2004, '7000', 64],
    ['Company 4', 2004, '9000', 65],
    ['Company 4', 2008, '4000', 66],
    ['Company 4', 2008, '7000', 67],
    ['Company 4', 2008, '1000', 68],
    ['Company 4', 2009, '4000', 69],
    ['Company 4', 2009, '7000', 70],
    ['Company 4', 2009, '6000', 71],
    ['Company 4', 2010, '4000', 72],
    ['Company 4', 2010, '7000', 73],
    ['Company 4', 2010, '9000', 74],
]

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['company', 'year', 'industry', 'value'])

Most of companies in my data looks like Company 1; however, a few of them ~ 10% looks like company 4 with the two main issues:

The year is not continuous
Some industries appear in some year but then disappear in other year

My objective is to obtaining value_lag1, value_lag2, .. for each company-year-industry. This means we need to fill in missing industries in each year available. For example, Company 4, in year 2010, we need to fill the missing 1000, 3000 and 6000 that appears in previous years
This is my expected output:
       company  year industry  value  value_lag1  value_lag2
68   Company 4  2000     1000 56.000         NaN         NaN
69   Company 4  2000     3000    NaN         NaN         NaN
70   Company 4  2000     4000 54.000         NaN         NaN
71   Company 4  2000     6000    NaN         NaN         NaN
72   Company 4  2000     7000 55.000         NaN         NaN
73   Company 4  2000     9000    NaN         NaN         NaN
74   Company 4  2001     1000    NaN      56.000         NaN
75   Company 4  2001     3000    NaN         NaN         NaN
76   Company 4  2001     4000 57.000      54.000         NaN
77   Company 4  2001     6000 59.000         NaN         NaN
78   Company 4  2001     7000 58.000      55.000         NaN
79   Company 4  2001     9000    NaN         NaN         NaN
80   Company 4  2003     1000    NaN         NaN         NaN
81   Company 4  2003     3000 62.000         NaN         NaN
82   Company 4  2003     4000 60.000         NaN         NaN
83   Company 4  2003     6000    NaN         NaN         NaN
84   Company 4  2003     7000 61.000         NaN         NaN
85   Company 4  2003     9000    NaN         NaN         NaN
86   Company 4  2004     1000    NaN         NaN         NaN
87   Company 4  2004     3000    NaN      62.000         NaN
88   Company 4  2004     4000 63.000      60.000         NaN
89   Company 4  2004     6000    NaN         NaN         NaN
90   Company 4  2004     7000 64.000      61.000         NaN
91   Company 4  2004     9000 65.000         NaN         NaN
92   Company 4  2008     1000 68.000         NaN         NaN
93   Company 4  2008     3000    NaN         NaN         NaN
94   Company 4  2008     4000 66.000         NaN         NaN
95   Company 4  2008     6000    NaN         NaN         NaN
96   Company 4  2008     7000 67.000         NaN         NaN
97   Company 4  2008     9000    NaN         NaN         NaN
98   Company 4  2009     1000    NaN      68.000         NaN
99   Company 4  2009     3000    NaN         NaN         NaN
100  Company 4  2009     4000 69.000      66.000         NaN
101  Company 4  2009     6000 71.000         NaN         NaN
102  Company 4  2009     7000 70.000      67.000         NaN
103  Company 4  2009     9000    NaN         NaN         NaN
104  Company 4  2010     1000    NaN         NaN      68.000
105  Company 4  2010     3000    NaN         NaN         NaN
106  Company 4  2010     4000 72.000      69.000      66.000
107  Company 4  2010     6000    NaN      71.000         NaN
108  Company 4  2010     7000 73.000      70.000      67.000
109  Company 4  2010     9000 74.000         NaN         NaN

My best try so far is:

Write a defined function that utilize multi-index by product to fill missing industries
Iteration over by group
Write a defined function to get lag value

My code:
Step 01: Defined function to fill missing industries
def fill_missing(data, index=['company', 'year', 'industry'], cols_keep=['value']):

    # Step 01: keep key cols
    data = data[index+cols_keep].copy()
    
    # Step 02: Data set index
    data = data.set_index(index).copy()

    # Perform Multi-Index Product then Reset-Index
    nlevel = len(index)
    mux    = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([data.index.levels[i] for i in range(nlevel)], names=index)
    data   = data.reindex(mux).reset_index()
    
    return data

Step 02: Lag defined function
def varlag(data, key=['gvkey'], time='year', col=['at'], tt=[1]):

    # sort data:
    data.sort_values(by=(key+[time]), ignore_index=True, inplace=True)

    # Create lag/lead check:
    for t in tt:
        data[f'yearlag{t}'] = data.groupby(key)[time].shift(t)
        data[f'clag{t}']    = np.where((data[time]-t) == data[f'yearlag{t}'], 1.0, np.NaN)

    # Loop over all cols:
    for c in col:
        for t in tt:
            data[f'{c}_lag{t}'] = data[f'{c}'].shift(t)*data[f'clag{t}']

        data = data.copy()

    prefix = ['yearlag', 'clag']
    cols   = data.columns[data.columns.str.startswith(tuple(prefix))]
    data.drop(columns=cols, inplace=True)

    return data

Step 03: iteration by group and apply the two functions
out = pd.DataFrame()
for gr in df['company'].unique():
    tem = df.loc[df['company']==gr].copy()

    # Apply the fill_missing
    tem = fill_missing(tem, index=['company', 'year', 'industry'], cols_keep=['value'])

    # Concat with out
    out = pd.concat([out, tem], axis=0, ignore_index=True)


out = varlag(out, key=['company', 'industry'], time='year', col=['value'], tt=[1,2])

I have two questions:

Is there any possible error for my method?
Do you have any suggestions to improve the efficiency, or any other approach is welcome to share. I want to learn


what is removefragment(data) in step02?

@PandaKim: Thanks for mention, it is just a copy function I write in a fancy style to avoid fragment issue when manipulating many columns

Code
When the shape of the data frame changes by group, I think it easiest to define a custom function and then use groupby + apply. Of course, it may not be the most efficient.
# define function get_lag
def get_lag(d):
    d1 = pd.DataFrame(
        {'company': d['company'].iloc[0],
         'year': range(d['year'].min(), d['year'].max() + 1)}
    )
    s1 = d['industry'].drop_duplicates().sort_values()
    df = d1.merge(s1, how='cross').merge(d, how='outer')
    g = df.groupby('industry')['value']
    df['value_lag1'] = g.shift(1)
    df['value_lag2'] = g.shift(2)
    return df[df['year'].isin(d['year'].unique())]

# groupby + apply + get_lag
out = (
    df.groupby(df['company'].tolist(), group_keys=False)
      .apply(get_lag).reset_index(drop=True)
)

# check head 10 rows of "Company 4"
print(out[out['company'].eq('Company 4')].head(10))

print:
      company  year industry  value  value_lag1  value_lag2
68  Company 4  2000     1000   56.0         NaN         NaN
69  Company 4  2000     3000    NaN         NaN         NaN
70  Company 4  2000     4000   54.0         NaN         NaN
71  Company 4  2000     6000    NaN         NaN         NaN
72  Company 4  2000     7000   55.0         NaN         NaN
73  Company 4  2000     9000    NaN         NaN         NaN
74  Company 4  2001     1000    NaN        56.0         NaN
75  Company 4  2001     3000    NaN         NaN         NaN
76  Company 4  2001     4000   57.0        54.0         NaN
77  Company 4  2001     6000   59.0         NaN         NaN

